# how can you dynamically load an Android activity or class from an external jar file?

Tags: android, class, load, dynamic

this question actually has a couple of parts:

1. how do you create an external jar file that can be loaded dynamically?  Can you just load an .apk file as a .jar file?  can you load classes.dex instead?  do you need to use the dx tool to convert a jar file to do this?
2. I see this piece of code to dynamically load a class:

   ```
       String jarfile = "test2.jar";
       DexClassLoader classloader = new DexClassLoader(
           jarfile, "/tmp", null, getClass().getClassLoader());
       Class<?> myclass = classloader.loadClass("Test2Activity");
   ```

In this case, where would the jar file be located?  In other words, when I install my main android app, I would need the path to the test2.jar file.

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible, at the very least a reference for every Activity you can initiate needs to exist in your project manifest. So even if this were possible I think it would still fail. Have you tried looking into [Setting up a Library Project](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) as an alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm actually looking for a similar answer - 
I've managed to find a way to dynamically load jar files to an android application - Right here on stack overflow through this link : 
*-Everything you need is here - Except I've added some things I spent time trying to figure out below the link- which may be useful to you*

**http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453614/how-can-i-load-a-jar-file-dynamically-in-an-android-application-4-0-3**

Here are some things to keep in mind:

1. When creating the .jar : You only need the .class file that needs to be dynamically loaded -  you do not need to include the interface IPeripheral in the .jar file.
2. Build the .jar file using an IDE - I wouldn't use the following command to edit the default manifest file made by calling the jar option in command line - Like this :"jar cmf manifest-addition jar-file input-file(s)". Instead open up eclipse, Goto File> Export > Java> Jar File and follow that along.
3. When it comes to selecting the manifest file - Select customized, and simply create the manifest file within the project as an untitle text file and save it as Whatever.manifestMake sure this text file has one line empty at the end of the file!
4. In the example code from the link above: Make sure to double check what this line is really doing:

   ```
   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader myClassLoader = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(urls.get(index).toString(), ModuleLoader.class.getClassLoader());
   ```

The reason I say this is because urls.get(index).toString() will return file:/pathname, and what you want is simply path name. I just simply parsed this out to make it work.

1. To create the SDCard - simply do it from the android device manager - There is an option to set external storage - select a size. In DDMS you will be able to open "File Explorer", you will find sdcard in the mnt folder and be able to push your jar file into the sd card folder.
2. This is what my Main_activity class looks like, that calls the module loader.

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends Activity 
   {
       private static Context context;
       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {
           super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
           setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

           //Get this classes context
           MainActivity.context = getApplicationContext();

           // method to return a list of modules that all implement the interface IPeripheral 
           List<IPeripheral> modules = ModuleLoader.loadModules("/mnt/sdcard", getApplicationContext());

           //Accessing a method - and display is just a method that toasts.
           display(modules.get(0).getName());
       }
   }
   ```

   Hope this helps - I don't think its possible for you to dynamically add jar files which are Java files that are actually "screens" or android activities, as this would require you to pro-grammatically edit the Projects Android Manifest File that you are attempting to dynamically load the jar into. I don't think this will be possible as it poses a security risk.