# How can i Load a jar file dynamically in an android application (4.0.3)

Tags: android

I have an android application which has to load dynamically class ,an undefined number of a jar class which implemented an interface.

In fact, I look at a directory and list all the jar files which are in this directory
I open the manifest of the jar file and find the associated class and list them.
And after, i instancied a dexClassLoader to load all the jar files and to find if the classes i have found in the manisfest implement my interface.
Like this I can have all the class which implemented my interface without knowing them at the begginning

To resume, i have a list of class jar which implement my interface but the list is unknown by my android application and by me. The list of jar class can changed each time i launch my application.

But when i tried to create the DexClassLoader it is failed. I have always a null pointer

```
DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),dexOutputDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
```

To make my test i used the emulator. I have copied with my DDMS the jar files into the directory
/data/data/com.example.Myappli/JarFilesDirectory/*.jar

Notice that my jar file contents the dex file

I read a lot of thing about this. Some permissions issues
I have tried every thing but not found the solution

Can someone help me please !!!

here the content of a manifest of a jar file

Manifest-Version: 1.0

Module-Class: com.example.asktester.AskPeripheral

Here my code :

public class ModuleLoader {

```
private static List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>(); 

private static List<String> getModuleClasses(String folder)
{ 
    List<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>(); 

    //we are listing the jar files
    File[] files = new File(folder).listFiles(new ModuleFilter()); 

    for(File f : files)
    { 
        JarFile jarFile = null; 

        try 
        { 
            //we open the jar file
            jarFile = new JarFile(f); 

            //we recover the manifest 
            Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest(); 

            //we recover the class
            String moduleClassName = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Module-Class"); 

            classes.add(moduleClassName); 

            urls.add(f.toURI().toURL()); 
        }
        catch (IOException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        finally
        { 
            if(jarFile != null)
            { 
                try
                { 
                    jarFile.close(); 
                }
                catch (IOException e) 
                { 
                    e.printStackTrace(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 

    return classes; 
} 

private static class ModuleFilter implements FileFilter { 
    @Override 
    public boolean accept(File file) { 
        return file.isFile() && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar"); 
    } 
}

private static ClassLoader classLoader; 

public static List<IPeripheral> loadModules(String folder, Context CurrentContext) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
{ 
    List<IPeripheral> modules = new ArrayList<IPeripheral>(); 

    List<String> classes = getModuleClasses(folder);


    final File dexInternalStoragePath = new File(CurrentContext.getDir("dex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE),"ask.dex");

     File dexOutputDir = CurrentContext.getDir("dex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

     final File dexClasses = new File(CurrentContext.getDir("dex", Context.MODE_PRIVATE),"ASK.jar");
     DexFile dexFile = DexFile.loadDex(dexClasses.getAbsolutePath(), dexOutputDir.getAbsolutePath(), 0);




    DexClassLoader classLoader = new DexClassLoader(dexInternalStoragePath.getAbsolutePath(),dexOutputDir.getAbsolutePath(), null, ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
    //Class<?> myClass = classLoader.loadClass("com.example.asktester.AskPeripheral");



            if(IPeripheral.class.isAssignableFrom(myClass )){ 
                Class<IPeripheral> castedClass = (Class<IPeripheral>)myClass ; 

                IPeripheral module = castedClass.newInstance(); 

                modules.add(module); 
        }  
    }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) 
        { 
            e1.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
        catch (InstantiationException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
        catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 
    } 

    return modules; 
}
```

Answer (score 18):

I found the solution to my issue.

To load dynamically jar, classes which implement an interface in an android application, some jobs need to be done in the jar :

- Create your own manisfest for the jar and put this information

  ```
   Manifest-Version: 1.0
   Module-Class: com.example.myjar.MyPeripheral
  ```
- Export your jar using eclipse and put in parameter that it uses its own manisfest
- Create the classes.dex associated to the jar 
  (this file is needed by the Dalvik VM, simply jar can not be read by the dalvik VM)

  ```
  dx --dex --output=C:\classes.dex C:\MyJar.jar
  ```

Be carefull, the name of the dex file MUST BE **classes.dex**

- Add the file classes.dex in the jar file

  ```
  aapt add C:\MyJar.jar C:\classes.dex
  ```
- You need also to have the right to write into the dalvik cache directory

  ```
     adb shell chmod 777 /data/dalvik-cache
  ```

  Do it each time, your relaunch your emulator
- put this jar file into the emulator for example on the SDcard
- Use a PathClassLoader to load the jar file

  ```
  dalvik.system.PathClassLoader myClassLoader = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader("/Sdcard/MyJar.jar", ModuleLoader.class.getClassLoader());
  ```

NB :  the LogCat in Eclipse gives you precious information. Do not forget to look at its messages

Below, the code :

**My interface** :

```
package com.example.StandartPeripheral; 

public interface IPeripheral {

    public boolean Initialize();
    public boolean configure();
    public boolean execute();
    public String GetName();
}
```

**MyPeripheral which implements the interface**

```
public class MyPeripheral implements IPeripheral {

    //public static void main(String[] args) {}

    private final String PeripheralName = "MyPeripheral";

    public boolean Initialize()
    {

        System.out.println("Initialize "); 
        return true;
    };

    public boolean configure()
    {
        System.out.println("Configure !"); 
        return true;
    };

    public boolean execute()
    {
        System.out.println("Execute !"); 
        return true;
    };

    public String GetName()
    {
        return PeripheralName;
    }

}
```

**How to load dynamically the jar files**

```
package com.example.ModuleLoader;


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileFilter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;
import java.util.jar.Manifest;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Context;

import com.example.StandartPeripheral.IPeripheral;


public class ModuleLoader { 

    private static List<URL> urls = new ArrayList<URL>(); 


    // to retrieve the unknown list of jar files contained in the directory folder
        // in my case it was in the SDCard folder
        // link to create a SDCard directory on the Eclipse emulator
        // http://blog.lecacheur.com/2010/01/14/android-avoir-acces-a-une-carte-memoire-dans-lemulateur/
        // retrieve the classes of all this jar files and their URL (location)

    private static List<String> getModuleClasses(String folder)
    { 
        List<String> classes = new ArrayList<String>(); 

        //we are listing the jar files
        File[] files = new File(folder).listFiles(new ModuleFilter()); 

        for(File f : files)
        { 
            JarFile jarFile = null; 

            try 
            { 
                //we open the jar file
                jarFile = new JarFile(f); 

                //we recover the manifest 
                Manifest manifest = jarFile.getManifest(); 

                //we recover the class name of our peripherals thanks to ours manifest
                String moduleClassName = manifest.getMainAttributes().getValue("Module-Class"); 

                classes.add(moduleClassName); 

                urls.add(f.toURI().toURL()); 
            }
            catch (IOException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
            finally
            { 
                if(jarFile != null)
                { 
                    try
                    { 
                        jarFile.close(); 
                    }
                    catch (IOException e) 
                    { 
                        e.printStackTrace(); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        return classes; 
    } 

    private static class ModuleFilter implements FileFilter { 
        @Override 
        public boolean accept(File file) { 
            return file.isFile() && file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jar"); 
        } 
    }

    //This function loads the jar file into the dalvik system
        // retrieves the associated classes using its name
        // and try to know if the loaded classes are implementing our interface


    public static List<IPeripheral> loadModules(String folder, Context CurrentContext)  { 
        List<IPeripheral> modules = new ArrayList<IPeripheral>(); 

        List<String> classes = getModuleClasses(folder);

            int index  = 0;
        for(String c : classes)
        { 
            try
            { 
                dalvik.system.PathClassLoader myClassLoader = new dalvik.system.PathClassLoader(urls.get(index).toString(), ModuleLoader.class.getClassLoader());
                Class<?> moduleClass = Class.forName(c, true, myClassLoader); 
                //check and cast to an interface, then use it
                if(IPeripheral.class.isAssignableFrom(moduleClass))             
                { 
                    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
                    Class<IPeripheral> castedClass = (Class<IPeripheral>)moduleClass; 

                    IPeripheral module =  (IPeripheral)moduleClass.newInstance(); 

                    modules.add(module); 
                }  
                index++;
        }
            catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) 
            { 
                e1.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
            catch (InstantiationException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            }
            catch (IllegalAccessException e) 
            { 
                e.printStackTrace(); 
            } 
        } 

        return modules; 
    }

}
```

Answer (score 8):

It would also be a good idea to use the ClassLoader rather than the Dalvik path class loader:

```
  ClassLoader cl = new DexClassLoader(url, ApplicationConstants.ref_currentActivity.getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(), null, ModuleList.class.getClassLoader());
```

Where url is the location of the file you are loading "from".
ApplicationConstants.ref_currentActivity is simply an activity class - my implementation is fairly complicated due to dynamic modular loading - so I needed to keep track of it this way - but others can probably just use "this" if that class is already an activity.

The MAIN reason for using the class loader over the dalvik one - is that it doesn't require files to be written to cache, and therefore the permission chmod 777 /data/dalvik-cache is unrequired - and of course you also wouldn't need to pass this command from root on a rooted phone pro-grammatically either.

It's always best to not have users forced to root their phones, simply because your app requires it. Especially if your app is a more professional "meant-for-company-use-type"  -.Work Policies against the use of rooted phones are usually in place too.

If anyone has any questions on modular loading - please feel free to ask.
The base of my current code is all thanks to Virginie Voirin, along with my own modifications. Good luck all!