# How to create 2 jars for pro and lite with same name in Android/Eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jar, google-play

I have a pro version and a free version.
What I plan to do is to put my code in a jar (lib) and have a flag reg=1 in code itself.
And I will build 2 jars one with reg=0 for free and other with reg=1 for pro.

Now Once I have the free installed, if I install the pro, I see that the new jar (pro reg=1) has not replaced the older one,

How to do that?

Comment: jar is the library projec

Answer (score 0):

You can not have 2 jars with the same name. You need to give them different names and load them dynamically. To load a jar dynamically you can look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453614/how-can-i-load-a-jar-file-dynamically-in-an-android-application-4-0-3)

Comment: How to do it in android as jars in apk are in separate folder how can lite version load paid version jar