# programmatically / dynamically include classes.dex into jar file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jvm, dalvik

I am looking for a way to programmatically load some classes and other files from a jar file into my Android application at its runtime.

The purpose of this is, so the functionality of the application can be increased with the help of the classes and other files contained in the jar file. I have tried to use the java.net.URLClassLoader, but that did not work due to the Android Dalvik VM only being capable of loading jar files that contain the "classes.dex" file. Those special jar files would then be loaded by the [DexClassLoader](https://developer.android.com/reference/dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.html) as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453614/how-can-i-load-a-jar-file-dynamically-in-an-android-application-4-0-3/13139921) thread.

However, i am searching for a solution where the classes.dex file could be created from and added to the jar file **programmatically and not manually**.
So far i have tried to perform this procedure manually in the cli of my OS (Windows10) due to testing purposes, but that did not work either. Here is the output of my cli:

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2>dx --dex --output=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\classes.dex C:\Users\%USERNAME%\Downloads\Weather.jar
-Djava.ext.dirs=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\lib is not supported.  Use -classpath instead.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Note: "%USERNAME%" was replaced by the valid username. It just got censored for security reasons.

Here is the code of my current class loading solution which works perfectly fine on the regular JVM (JDK/JRE 9.0.4) but not in the Android application:

```
package chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp.plugins;

import android.util.Log;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Constructor;
import java.lang.reflect.GenericSignatureFormatError;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.MalformedParameterizedTypeException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;

import chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapi.android.Plugin;

/**
 * This class is responsible for executing the highly unstable process of getting a new instance
 * of a plugins main class. There is a total number of 11 exceptions to be thrown during this
 * procedure. Every exception get printed with its stack trace and a custom designed fatal error
 * message. The one and only method this class makes use of is loadPlugin(). The plugins are
 * loaded through the URIClassLoader. ATTENTION: If the package name of a class to be loaded 
 * is the same as one of the package names from the application in which this PluginLoader class
 * is used a conflict between the two same named packages is created. In this conflict the same
 * named package of your application is always going to be chosen first INSTEAD of the package
 * from a different .jar archive file.
 * 
 * @author ChrTopf
 *
 */
public class PluginLoader {

    private static final String TAG = "PluginLoader";
    private PluginInterface app;
    
    /**
     * Initializes a new plugin loader object.
     * @param app The plugin interface which is going to be used in the constructor of the plugins
     * main class. This interface delivers access to important methods to the plugin. (PluginInterface)
     */ 
    public PluginLoader(PluginInterface app) {
        this.app = app;
    }
    
    /**
     * This method loads the main class of a plugin from a specific package of a specific .jar archive file.
     * @param plugin_name The name of the plugin (only for GUI and debug, but important). (String)
     * @param jar_file The existing .java archive file of the plugin to be loaded. (File)
     * @param main_path The package path to the plugins main class. (String)
     * @return returns a new Instance of the plugins main class. (Plugin)
     */
    public Plugin loadPlugin(String plugin_name, File jar_file, String main_path) {
        try {
            //get the url e.g. the path to the .jar file of the plugin
            URL file_path = jar_file.toURI().toURL();
            //try to load the .jar archive
            URLClassLoader classloader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] {file_path});
            //load the main class from the archive as specified in the .properties file
            Class<?> plugin = classloader.loadClass(main_path);
            //get the constructor of the main plugin class
            Constructor<?> plugin_const = plugin.getDeclaredConstructor(PluginInterface.class);
            //prepare the constructor
            plugin_const.setAccessible(true);
            //get a new instance of the main plugin class using the prepared constructor
            Plugin new_plugin = (Plugin) plugin_const.newInstance(this.app);
            //close the classloader
            classloader.close();
            //return the new instance of the plugin
            return new_plugin;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "The configuration file of the plugin with the name " + plugin_name + " has an incorrect path to the .jar archive!");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "The configuration file of the plugin with the name " + plugin_name + " has an incorrect path to the main class! Or the plugin is made for a different smarthome server version.");
        } catch (TypeNotPresentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "The main class of the plugin with the name " + plugin_name + " has no superclass, but it needs to be plugin.Plugin!");
        } catch (MalformedParameterizedTypeException | GenericSignatureFormatError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "This should definitely not happen. Please contact the author of the smarthome server application or verfiy that you used java version 13.0.1 for your plugin with the name " + plugin_name);
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "A new instance of the main class could somehow not be constructed from the plugin " + plugin_name);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "A new instance of the main class could not be constructed from the plugin " + plugin_name + " because it is unknown to the smarthome server.");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "A new instance of the main class could not be constructed from the plugin " + plugin_name + " due to illegal Arguments.");
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "A new instance of the main class could not be constructed from the plugin " + plugin_name + " due to the constructor of the main class throwing an exception.");
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "A new instance of the main class could not be constructed from the plugin " + plugin_name + " because a specific method could not be found in the main plugin class.");
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "A new instance of the main class could not be constructed from the plugin " + plugin_name + " due to missing file system rights.");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "The classloader could not be closed successfully.");
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Note:** The loadPlugin() method returns a class from the jar file that is an interface of the Plugin class.

Due to the fact that the Dalvik VM cant load the class out of this type of jar file, I am getting the following error in the LogCat:

```
2020-12-05 13:36:26.648 15121-15121/chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp2 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp2, PID: 15121
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp2/chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp.main.MainActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3375)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3514)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2110)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: can't load this type of class file
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:591)
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:469)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:69)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:94)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:59)
        at chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp.plugins.PluginWrap.load(PluginWrap.java:82)
        at chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp.plugins.PluginManager.loadPlugin(PluginManager.java:178)
        at chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp.plugins.PluginManager.startExec(PluginManager.java:131)
        at chrtopf.ddns.net.smarthomeapp.main.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:105)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7815)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7804)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3350)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3514) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2110) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7697) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I am using Android API Level 29 and Android Studio 4.0.1

Thank you for your support in advance!

Comment: "I am looking for a way to programmatically load some classes and other files from a jar file into my Android application at its runtime" -- note that this will violate the distribution terms of the Play Store and perhaps other app distribution channels.

Comment: I am currently not interested in putting my application on the Google Play Store. Its just an experimental one that only runs on my own device. But thank you for your information though!

Answer (score 0):

So after doing a ton of research and lots of coding, i can finally provide a better solution/answer to my original question.

As CommonsWare commented on my last post, i searched the google docs to find a way to programmatically extend the functionality of my app. And i fond one! It is called "dynamic feature modules" or "on demand delivery" and is part of the android app bundle. With this functionality it is possible to download and install additional features for your app during its runtime. And the best part about it: It does not interfere with the google play distribution terms!

But before you settle on this solution here are a view points to be mentioned:

1. If you want to test your app and especially the dowloading and installing process of the on demand dynamic feature modules you need to upload the entire app bundle (also your base application module) to google play. (TIPP: Use "internal app sharing" first to test it)
2. For the first point to work, you need to own a developer account for the google play console.
3. Before you can create dynmic feature modules in your app project, you first have to convert it from an apk (instant app) to an android app bundle.
4. A dynmic feature module can be requested and installed from your application during runtime using the google play core library. (which needs to be added as a dependency in your base application module)
5. A dynmic feature module can also include extra librarys (such as jar archives) just as a base application module does. So in my case i could stick to the jar files i already had prepard to implement and test my original solution with the class loader.
6. If your dynamic feature module only needs to contain some libraries you can delete the empty java packages, which are getting generated by default if you create a new dynmic feature module in android studio.
7. Last but not least, you can create a new instance of a class in your dynmic feature module (also works with the classes of libraries located in the dfm) as shown in the following example:

```
//try to create a new instance of a plugin / some class from your library
try {
    Plugin plugin = (Plugin) Plugin.class.forName("your.java.library.classpath.to.class").newInstance();
    // do something with the newly created class
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (java.lang.InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Note: The class with the name "Plugin" was just used as an example here.

I hope this was also helpful for you to show how easy designing a modular android app is once you know what needs to be done. I strongly advise you to have a look into the google docs and read through them before you get any deeper into this topic as it can get a bit confusing or complicated. When it comes to accessing code or resources from your dynamic feature modules.